# Не могу корректно отправить результат поиска, задваивается

Tags: java

Коллеги, помогите подкорректировать код. Суть такая, что новости, которые нашлись, должны уйти одним письмом. А получается чушь задвоенная и уходит два письма (при данном результате - где всего нашлось 2 новости, смотрите скрин).
Может **Email_Sender.e_send(text);** не там где надо, или метод **concatText** неправильный..подскажите

[image: скрин результата]

```
public class News_from_RSS {
private static final String[] sources = {"https://russian.rt.com/rss", "https://lenta.ru/rss/articles"};
static String text;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
            RSSFeedParser parser = new RSSFeedParser(sources[i]);
            Feed feed = parser.readFeed();
            for (FeedMessage message : feed.getMessages()) {

                //вводим любое ключевое слово для поиска конкретных новостей
                if (message.toString().indexOf("Барселона") >= 1) {
                    concatText(message.toString());
                }

            }
            Email_Sender.e_send(text);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void concatText(String in) {
    text = in.concat(in);
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void concatText(String in) {
    text = in.concat(in);
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Вы сами дублируете текст: `text = in.concat(in);`

> Метод `concat()` — возвращает строку со значением строки, переданной в метод и приложенной к концу строки, используемой для вызова этого метода. Проще говоря метод `concat()` в Java объединяет строки, путем добавления одной строки в конец к другой.

**UPD:**

```
public class News_from_RSS {
private static final String[] sources = {"https://russian.rt.com/rss", "https://lenta.ru/rss/articles"};
static String text = "";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
            RSSFeedParser parser = new RSSFeedParser(sources[i]);
            Feed feed = parser.readFeed();
            for (FeedMessage message : feed.getMessages()) {

                //вводим любое ключевое слово для поиска конкретных новостей
                if (message.toString().indexOf("Барселона") >= 1) {
                    concatText(message.toString());
                }

            }
        }
        Email_Sender.e_send(text);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void concatText(String in) {
    text += in;
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Comment: @mrprogre обновил ответ